# how to save resized images using ImageDataGenerator and flow_from_directory in keras

Tags: keras, keras-2

I am resizing my RGB images stored in a folder(two classes) using following code:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
dataset=ImageDataGenerator()
dataset.flow_from_directory('/home/1',target_size=(50,50),save_to_dir='/home/resized',class_mode='binary',save_prefix='N',save_format='jpeg',batch_size=10)
```

My data tree is like following:

```
1/
 1_1/
     img1.jpg
     img2.jpg
     ........
 1_2/
     IMG1.jpg
     IMG2.jpg
     ........
resized/
        1_1/ (here i want to save resized images of 1_1)
        2_2/ (here i want to save resized images of 1_2)
```

After running the code i am getting following output but not images:

```
Found 271 images belonging to 2 classes.
Out[12]: <keras.preprocessing.image.DirectoryIterator at 0x7f22a3569400>
```

How to save images?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Heres a very simple version of saving augmented images of one image wherever you want:

## Step 1. Initialize image data generator

Here we figure out what changes we want to make to the original image and generate the augmented images
You can read up about the diff effects here-   https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=10, width_shift_range=0.1, 
height_shift_range=0.1,shear_range=0.15, 
zoom_range=0.1,channel_shift_range = 10, horizontal_flip=True)
```

## Step 2: Here we pick the original image to perform the augmentation on

read in the image

```
image_path = 'C:/Users/Darshil/gitly/Deep-Learning/My 
Projects/CNN_Keras/test_augment/caty.jpg'

image = np.expand_dims(ndimage.imread(image_path), 0)
```

## step 3: pick where you want to save the augmented images

```
save_here = 'C:/Users/Darshil/gitly/Deep-Learning/My 
Projects/CNN_Keras/test_augment'
```

## Step 4. we fit the original image

```
datagen.fit(image)
```

## step 5: iterate over images and save using the "save_to_dir" parameter

```
for x, val in zip(datagen.flow(image,                    #image we chose
        save_to_dir=save_here,     #this is where we figure out where to save
         save_prefix='aug',        # it will save the images as 'aug_0912' some number for every new augmented image
        save_format='png'),range(10)) :     # here we define a range because we want 10 augmented images otherwise it will keep looping forever I think
pass
```

Comment: `range(10)` is bit confusing. instead `batch_size=total number of images` can be used. And instead of `pass`, `break` can be used

Answer (score 6):

Its only a declaration, you must use that generator, for example, `.next()`

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
dataset=ImageDataGenerator()
image = dataset.flow_from_directory('/home/1',target_size=(50,50),save_to_dir='/home/resized',class_mode='binary',save_prefix='N',save_format='jpeg',batch_size=10)
image.next()
```

then you will see images in `/home/resized`

Answer (score 5):

The `flow_from_directory` method gives you an "iterator", as described in your output. An iterator doesn't really do anything on its own. It's waiting to be iterated over, and only then the actual data will be read and generated.

An iterator in Keras for fitting is to be used like this:

```
generator = dataset.flow_from_directory('/home/1',target_size=(50,50),save_to_dir='/home/resized',class_mode='binary',save_prefix='N',save_format='jpeg',batch_size=10)

for inputs,outputs in generator:

    #do things with each batch of inputs and ouptus
```

Normally, instead of doing the loop above, you just pass the generator to a `fit_generator` method. There is no real need to do a for loop:

```
model.fit_generator(generator, ......)
```

Keras will only save images after they're loaded and augmented by iterating over the generator.

Comment: Please tell me what lines i have to add fro saving images. and one more thing if we are not saving images, then where keras saving it and processing it. Is keras using ram for it?

Comment: Just do the loop or train with the generator. Keras will use the RAM, whether it saves the images or not.

Comment: I donot want to train. Just want save images, and this i instructed through `save_to_dir='/home/resized'` to keras. I do understand for loop for iterator, but i donot understand what i write after for loop, i given all instruction through `dataset.flow_from_directory`

Comment: You must do the loop (it doesn't matter what is inside the loop).

Comment: when i write `i=1` loop is infinitely running, and i manually stopped get, and getting 100's og images. i can't understand the output

Comment: I know it's silly question but i am very knew to this preprocessing part

Comment: Oh, I forgot that part.... keras generators are infinite indeed. They will repeat themselves indefinitely. You must define the end of the loop yourself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161296/discussion-between-hitesh-and-daniel-moller).

Comment: How to calculate overall Test Loss and Test Accuracy in this case, because generally i use `score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])` but here we donot have y_test

Comment: yes i know, i can use evaluate_generator and predict_generator. I am doing binary classification (2 class) so i donot know my model is taking class 1 as 0 or class 1 as 1. Actually i want to calculate confusion matrix also.

Comment: Maybe use: "predict_generator" then to see the results?

Comment: I have used it, but that give me output data prediction, but i donot know what my model takes as input. which class to zero and which class to one

Comment: reference from above question, my model will take all 1_1 folder images as 0 or 1?

Comment: Make a test: `inputs, outputs = next(generator)`. See for each image what the model is using.

Comment: It gives me output as (10,1) but my total outputs are (21,1)

Answer (score 1):

You may try this simple code example and modify it according to your need:

(It generates augmented images from your data and then save them into a different folder)

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator


data_dir = 'data/train' #Due to the structure of ImageDataGenerator, you need to have another folder under train contains your data, for example: data/train/faces
save_dir = 'data/resized'


datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)


resized = datagen.flow_from_directory(data_dir, target_size=(224, 224),
                                save_to_dir=save_dir,
                                color_mode="rgb", # Choose color mode
                                class_mode='categorical',
                                shuffle=True,
                                save_prefix='N',
                                save_format='jpg', # Formate
                                batch_size=1)


for in in range(len(resized)):
    resized.next()
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to save the images under a folder having same name as label then you can loop over a list of labels and call the augmentation code within the loop.

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator  

# Augmentation + save augmented images under augmented folder

IMAGE_SIZE = 224
BATCH_SIZE = 500
LABELS = ['lbl_a','lbl_b','lbl_c']

for label in LABELS:
  datagen_kwargs = dict(rescale=1./255)  
  dataflow_kwargs = dict(target_size=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE), 
                        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, interpolation="bilinear")

  train_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=40,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    width_shift_range=0.1, height_shift_range=0.1,
    shear_range=0.1, zoom_range=0.1,
    **datagen_kwargs)

  train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
      'original_images', subset="training", shuffle=True, save_to_dir='aug_images/'+label, save_prefix='aug', classes=[label], **dataflow_kwargs)
  
  # Following line triggers execution of train_generator
  batch = next(train_generator)
```

So why do this when generator can directly be passed to model? In case, you want to use the `tflite-model-maker` which does not accept a generator and accepts labelled data under folder for each label:

```
from tflite_model_maker import ImageClassifierDataLoader
data = ImageClassifierDataLoader.from_folder('aug_images')
```

**Result**

```
aug_images
| 
|__ lbl_a
|   |
|   |_____aug_img_a.png
|
|__ lbl_b
|   |
|   |_____aug_img_b.png
| 
|__ lbl_c
|   |
|   |_____aug_img_c.png
```

**Note:** You need to ensure the folders already exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,
                     rotation_range =15, 
                     width_shift_range = 0.2, 
                     height_shift_range = 0.2, 
                     shear_range=0.2, 
                     zoom_range=0.2, 
                     horizontal_flip = True, 
                     fill_mode = 'nearest', 
                     brightness_range=[0.5, 1.5])
```

```
DATA_DIR = 'splited/train/'
save_here = 'aug dataset/train/normal2/'

cancer = os.listdir(DATA_DIR + 'cancer/')
for i, image_name in enumerate(cancer):
    try:
        if (image_name.split('.')[1] == 'png'):
            image = np.expand_dims(cv2.imread(DATA_DIR +'classs 1/' + image_name), 0)
            for x, val in zip(datagen.flow(image, #image we chose save_to_dir=save_here,     #this is where we figure out where to save
                save_prefix='aug',        # it will save the images as 'aug_0912' some number for every new augmented image
                save_format='png'),range(10)) :     # here we define a range because we want 10 augmented images otherwise it will keep looping forever I think
                    pass
    except Exception:
        print("Could not read image {} with name {}".format(i, image_name))
```